# How to get key values from default dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a default dictionary with name df:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'DE': 1, u'WV': 1, u'HI': 1, u'WY': 1, u'NH': 2, u'NJ': 1, u'NM': 1, u'TX': 1, u'LA': 1, u'NC': 1, u'NE': 1, u'TN': 1, u'RI': 1, u'VA': 1, u'CO': 1, u'AK': 1, u'AR': 1, u'IL': 1, u'GA': 1, u'IA': 1, u'MA': 1, u'ID': 1, u'ME': 1, u'OK': 2, u'MN': 1, u'MI': 1, u'KS': 1, u'MT': 1, u'MS': 1, u'SC': 2, u'KY': 1, u'OR': 1, u'SD': 1})
```

how do I get the keys of this dictionary whose values are more than 1.

If I do `[df[val] for val in df if df[val]>1]`

I get the output as `[2, 2, 2]`

If I print `[df.keys() for val in df if df[val]>1]` Still I donot get the key values, I need the keys that has values more than 2 like this `['SC', 'OK', 'NH']`
How do I do that??

Comment: `[val for val in df...]`? But it would be clearer to call it `key`; that's what you iterate over, by default: `[key for key in df if df[key] > 1]`. Alternatively, `[key for key, val in df.items() if val > 1]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I call .key I get an attribute error

Comment: I never suggested `.key`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe [str(val) for val in df if df[val]>1] this worked, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

Reading from a dictionary created using `defaultdict()` is the same as a normal `dict`.

To get the keys which have values > 1, you would do:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(...)
print [key for key, value in my_dict.iteritems() if value > 1]
```

If you're using Python 3 then it's `my_dict.items()`.

Comment: [str(val) for val in df if df[val]>1] this is much simpler. I also found an alternative to default dict. Counter(http://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html) and countStates.most_common()

Comment: Well if you're going to go that route it should at least be `[str(key) for key in df if df[key] > 1]`, considering those are keys, not values, that you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

We can use list compression method.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['HI'] = 1
>>> d['NH'] = 2
>>> d['WY'] = 1
>>> d['OK'] = 2
>>> [i[0] for i in d.items() if i[1]>1]
['NH', 'OK']
```